# Separate text between square brackets as a separate column in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following the following columns,

```
column_1 = ["Northern Rockies, British Columbia [9A87]", "Northwest Territories [2H89]", "Canada [00052A]", "Division No. 1, Newfoundland and Labrador [52A]"]
column_2 = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]
column_3 = [4, 4.5, 23, 1]

zipped = list(zip(column_1 , column_2, column_3))
df = pd.DataFrame(zipped, columns=['column_1' , 'column_2', 'column_3'])
```

I want to extract the text between the square brackets from the first column as a separate column. Below is the output I am looking for,

```
column_1 = ["Northern Rockies, British Columbia", "Northwest Territories", "Canada", "Division No. 1, Newfoundland and Labrador"]
column_2 = ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"]
column_3 = [4, 4.5, 23, 1]
column_4 = ["9A87", "2H89", "00052A", "52A"]

zipped = list(zip(column_1 , column_2, column_3, column_4))
df = pd.DataFrame(zipped, columns=['column_1' , 'column_2', 'column_3', 'column_4'])
```

I am using square bracket here but I think the solution should apply to any type of bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `str.extract` and `str.repalce` here:

```py
df["column_4"] = df["column_1"].str.extract(r'\[(.*?)\]')
df["column_1"] = df["column_1"].str.replace(r'\s*\[.*?\]$', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: Hi Tim! Thank you for providing a solution. However, this method does not change the first column. While I want to separate the bracketed text, I also want it removed from the first column.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized that my question had some missing pieces. So the first column is not single words. The updated solution works for single words but what if I had long strings? Would really appreciate it if you can take a look at the updated question.

Comment: Ok so I used the replace method and it works! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Hello, Salahuddin!
From the column_1, I assumed that square brackets or any kind of brackets come always after the text. eg. Northern Rockies, British Columbia [9A87]

```
df[['column_1','column_4']] = df['column_1'].str.extract(r'(.*)[\[\{\(](.*)[\]\}\)]',flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

This will work for any kind of brackets like [], (), {}

Comment: Hi Bhavesh! Thank you for the solution. Yes the square brackets always come after the text. Your solution is brief and elegant!

Comment: It's my pleasure that I could help you!